# Perl Program to parse through error log file, extract error message and output to new file

Tags: regex, perl

I need to write a perl program where I parse through an error log and output the error messages to a new file. I am having issues with setting up the regex to do this. In the error log, an error code starts with the word "ERROR" and the end of each error message ends with a ". " (period and then a space). I want to find all the errors, count them, and also output the entire error message of each error message to a new file.

I tried this but am having issues:

```
open(FH,"<$filetoparse");

    $outputfile='./errorlog.txt';
    open(OUTPUT,">$outputfile");
    $errorstart='ERROR';
    $errorend=". ";

    while(<FH>)
    {
    if (FH=~ /^\s*$errorstart/../$errorend/)   
    {
        print OUTPUT "success";
    }   
    else
    {
        print OUTPUT "failed";
    }
    }

}
```

the $errorstart and $errorend are something I saw online and am not sure if that is the correct way to code it.

Also I know the printing "Success" or "Failure" is not what I said I am looking for, I added that in to help with confirmed that the code works, I haven't tried coding for counting the error messages yet.

before this snippet of code I have a print statement asking the user for the location address of the .txt file they want to parse. I confirmed that particular section of code words properly. Thanks for any help! Let me know if more info is needed!

Here is an example of data that I will be using:

Sample Data

-----BEGIN LOAD-----
SUCCESS: file loaded properly .
SUCCESS: file loaded properly .
SUCCESS: file loaded properly .
SUCCESS: file loaded properly .
SUCCESS: file loaded properly .
SUCCESS: file loaded properly .
ERROR: the file was unable to load for an unknown reason .
SUCCESS: file loaded properly .
SUCCESS: file loaded properly .
ERROR: the file was unable to load this is just an example of a log file that   will span
multiple lines .
SUCCESS: file loaded properly .
------END LOAD-------

While the log may not necessarily NEED to span multiple lines, there will be some data throughout the log that will similar to how it is above. Every message logged starts with either SUCCESS or ERROR and the message is done when a " . " (whitespace-period-whitespace) is encountered. The log I want to parse through is 50,000 entries long so needless to say I would like to code so it will also identify multi-line error msgs as well as output the entire multi-line message to the output file.

**update**

I have written the code but for some reason it won't work. I think it has to do with the delimiter but I can't figure out what it is. The file I am using has messages that are separated by "whitespace period newline". Can you see what I'm doing wrong??

```
{
local $/ = " .\n";
if ($outputtype == 1)
{
    $outputfile="errorlog.txt";
    open(OUTPUT,">>$outputfile");
    $errorcount=0;
    $errortarget="ERROR";
    print OUTPUT "-----------Error Log-----------\n";
    {
    while(<FH>)
    {
    if ($_ =~ m/^$errortarget/)
    {
        print OUTPUT "$_\n";
        print OUTPUT "next code is: \n";
        $errorcount++;
    }
    }
    print OUTPUT "\nError Count : $errorcount\n";
    }
}
}
```

Comment: It's probably not the right answer, assuming your error is a single line. The range operator exists for multi-line records. Can you give some sample source data?

Comment: Please post a sample of your error logs. FYI: you probably could solve this even with a perl one-liner command instead of a long program however this depends on whether you want to get the job done quickly or learn some perl actually :)

Answer (score 4):

There are several problems with your code to start off.

- ALWAYS `use strict;` and `use warnings;`.
- 3 argument `open` is much less error prone. `open ( my $fh, "<", $filename ) or die $!;`
- Always check `open` actually worked.
- `FH =~` doesn't do what you think it does.
- range operator tests if you're between two chunks of text in code. This is particularly relevant for multi-line operations. If your error log isn't, then it's not what you need.

Assuming you've error data like this:

```
ERROR: something is broken.
WARNING: something might be broken.
INFO: not broken.
ERROR: still broken.
```

This code will do the trick:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $filetoparse = "myfile.txt";
my $outputfile  = "errorlog.txt";

open( my $input,  "<", $filetoparse ) or die $!;
open( my $output, ">", $outputfile )  or die $!;

my $count_of_errors = 0;
#set record delimiter
local $/ = " . \n";

while ( my $lines = <$input> ) {
    $lines =~ s/^-----\w+ LOAD-----\n//g; #discard any 'being/end load' lines. 
    if ( $lines =~ m/^ERROR/ ) {
        $count_of_errors++;
        print {$output} $lines;
    }
}
close ( $input );
close ( $output );

print "$count_of_errors errors found\n";
```

If you've multi-line error message, then you'll need a slightly different approach though.

Comment: True. Amended. It's good form if nothing else. One of the advantages of lexically scoped filehandles though is they auto close when they leave scope.

Comment: Thank you for your help!!! and to answer your question, there ARE multi-line error messages but they do follow the same convention of starting with "ERROR" and ending with a (period then a space)

Comment: @MI.Sarwar
In order to do multi-line error messages will I have to implement the $errorstart $errorend and range operator in the if statement?

    $errorstart="ERROR";
    $errorend=". ";
    if ($line=~ /^\s*$errorstart/../$errorend/)

Comment: Update your question with sample logs, and I will amend so it works. This approach reads one line at a time, so you need to do something a little different.  Exactly what depends on your log format.

Comment: @Sobrique updated. Thanks! I think I mentioned the other person that commented in my previous post, although you were the one that posted the Answer. Thanks so much! And yes, I am in this to learn how to code it properly, not just to get it done. :-) CODE-ON!

Comment: With that log, setting $/ to "." will do the trick. Edited,  but not tested because using my phone.

Comment: Is there a "whitespace-.-whitespace" (w/o dashes) between quotes or simply a period (".")

Comment: Can be either in all honesty, since it doesn't look like you have a '.' anywhere else. But I've set it according to your specification in the question in the code above.

Comment: Thank you @Sobrique, as I said this is only a sample of what the code looks like, there are plenty of "." 's throughout the actual log that I need to pass over to get to the end of certain errors, thanks so much for your help!

Comment: @Sobrique I updated my code but for some reason I cannot get it to work, any advice? I'm pretty confident that my error is in changing the delimiter. Again the proper deliver is supposed to be  "whitespace period newline" (" .\n")

Comment: Can I suggest opening a new question summarising the new problem? You'll get a better selection of answers. I can't easily tell given your code. My suggestion would be go for a very simple `while ( <$input> ) { print "\n---\n"; print; }` to show where the file is getting split up.